# C# - Calling functions from class variable in abstract class through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to use Reflection to call a function off of an class variable which is inside of an instance of my object.

I have a class that's defined similarly to this:

```
public abstract class Foo : IDisposable
{
    public Bar c { get; }
    <...snip...>
 }
```

Bar is a sealed class but I don't think that's related to my problem. Under a non-reflection case using this class looks like this:

```
Foo myFoo = someOtherObject.GetFoo();
myFoo.c.someFunc();
```

I need to do the same using reflection but can't access the c variable inside of my constructed Foo object.

I've already confirmed that my myFoo object is constructed correctly using reflective function calls, but I can't access the instance variable. Other topics have suggesting doing `myFoo.GetType().GetFields()` and then iterating through the fields to get the one I want but `GetFields()` returns nothing in both cases (reflection or no), so I'm not sure if the issue has something to do with it being defined as abstract or something else.

Is there another way for me to get the class variable?

Comment: If you call Type.GetProperties, you will get a collection PropertyInfo objects.  From there, you want to get the "property getter" (which is a MethodInfo you can Invoke).  Once you invoke it, you'll get the value for the object upon which it was invoked, and you can continue to play.
The first time you use Reflection to do anything, expect to spend a lot of time in the debugger spelunking the types that make up the world of Reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason nothing is returned is because `c` is not a field, but a property. To grossly oversimplify, properties in C# are glorified getter and setter methods expressed through the `{ get {} set {} }` syntax after what would otherwise be a field (which is what you believe to be working with). Your options here are to either make `c` a field by removing `{ get; }` (this is usually discouraged because then any code using your class can make changes to the field without your class being able to react to it) or by using the appropriate method to retrieve properties, namely `GetProperty()`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz0a8sxy(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Yup that's what it was - used to Java I guess :) Rest was straightforward